# How can I check whether a double has a fractional part?

Tags: c++

Basically I have two variables:

```
double halfWidth = Width / 2;
double halfHeight = Height / 2;
```

As they are being divided by 2, they will either be a whole number or a decimal. How can I check whether they are a whole number or a .5?

Comment: Are `Width` and `Height` integer or floating point values?  Unless they are `float` or `double`, you will always get an integer result since the division is performed on the basis of the types of `Width` or `Height` and 2 (all an integer type under this hypothesis), and the result is then converted to a `double`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`modf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/modf/), this should be sufficient:

```
 double intpart;

 if( modf( halfWidth, &intpart) == 0 )
 {
 // your code here
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to make sure that you're using double-precision floating-point math:

```
double halfWidth = Width / 2.0;
double halfHeight = Height / 2.0;
```

Because one of the operands is a double (namely, `2.0`), this will force the compiler to convert `Width` and `Height` to doubles before doing the math (assuming they're not already `double`s). Once converted, the division will be done in double-precision floating-point. So it will have a decimal, where appropriate.

The next step is to simply check it with [`modf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf).

```
double temp;
if(modf(halfWidth, &temp) != 0)
{
  //Has fractional part.
}
else
{
  //No fractional part.
}
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Does it need to? You're dividing an integer by 2; if it's not 0, it must be 0.5.

Comment: OK — I see you're interpreting the inputs a bit differently from me, and therefore coming up with a different answer (a valid answer given your expectation on the inputs). Quietly ignore me...I'll go away...

Answer (score 2):

You may discard a fractional part and compare the result with the original value using floor():

```
if (floor(halfWidth) == halfWidth) {
    // halfWidth is a whole number
} else {
    // halfWidth has a non-zero fractional part
}
```

As rightly pointed out by @Dávid Laczkó, it's a better solution than modf() because there's no need for an additional variable.

And according to my benchmarks (Linux, gcc 8.3.0, optimizations -O0...-O3), the floor() call consumes less CPU time than modf() on the modern notebook and server processors. The difference even growing with compiler optimizations enabled. Probably it's because the modf() has two arguments when the floor() has only one argument.

Comment: I think for this task it is better, than the accepted solution also because there's no need for an additional variable. I wonder if the processing work could be even more reduced by using a cast to an`int` instead of floor().

Comment: Cast to an `int` may lead to integer overflow because `double` variable can contain value ~ 1.7e+308 when `uint64_t`, for example, can only contain ~ 1.8e+19.

Comment: Checked just now casting a small `double` value to `int` and didn't register any difference in CPU time with floor() call. It's possible that floor() is doing almost the same.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course in general you can not do it - good point.

Comment: Then this might be the best practice for this task.